# Cant boot up Ubuntu from USB

Tags: usb, ssd

I dropped my laptop, apparently trashed the hard drive. Installed a new ssd. Made a bootable USB drive, 3 times with different USBs and cannot get my laptop to boot. I have fiddled around with bios settings but same thing happens every time. I select install Ubuntu then just blank screen. My laptop is an HP Pavilion spectre x360.  It had Windows 10 before the hard drive death.  Hope someone with the know how chimes in. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  After downloading Ubuntu, did you verify the download? (checksum) or test the usb-thumb-drive write?  Since yours won't boot, I'd suggest trying to boot the thumb-drive on another system to confirm it's bootable (ie. written correctly), then check media.